# How do I get auto increment using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I currently have a relational database that I am planning to migrate to neo4j. We have apis exposed that take ids as inputs in the urls like /entity/{id}/relatedEntities etc.These Ids are db generated auto increment Ids. There are multiple clients of these APIs that might have cached the Ids so in order to maintain backward compatibility I need to keep using these ids. My question is after migrating to neo4j when I start adding new entities how can continue generating these ids specially in a clustered environment (I plan to have multiple JVMs and master/client nodes for neo4j)?

Comment: Backward compatibility is overrated.

Answer (score 1):

As of Neo4j 3.0.6, auto-generated sequences are not part of the feature set.

You may be able to define sequence nodes with properties specifying the label of the sequence, lock on that node when you need a new number, increment and generate and unlock after, though that can be awkward. That should work in a clustered environment if it's a write operation, as writes should be performed on the master node of the cluster, but others with more experience in this area can confirm or deny that.

One alternate approach is to use UUIDs instead of sequences. You will need to handle them as strings instead of ints, and you'll lose the ability to do comparisons based on the generated id, but APOC Procedures has support for UUID generation, and mathematically they will be unique, and there won't be any collision with the previous numeric ids you've used in the past.